# Multiple object instance sharing global variable in Python

Tags: python, object, global-variables, multiple-instances

I want to have a global variable `x` that can be accessed by multiple object instances:
The module `Obj` should have something like:

```
x = 0

class Obj:  
  def set_x(self):    
      global x
      x = 2

  def print_x(self):    
      print x
```

...etc.

The other module (ex: main) instantiates the object obj:

```
obj1 = Obj.Obj()
obj1.set_x()
obj2 = Obj.Obj()
obj2.print_x
```

this should print 2

Comment: OK... so what is your question? Also, why wouldn't you just use a class attribute for that?

Comment: Instance methods take ``self`` as the first argument. I have edited the code in the question.

Comment: Whats ur question? When you tried wht did you get as output?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into an Idle session, and it works as-is.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for something like static variables (I'm not sure what they're called in Python). Have you tried something like:

```
class Obj:
   x = 0

   def set_x(self):
      Obj.x = Obj.x + 1

   def print_x(self):
      print Obj.x
```

Tests:

```
>>> obj1 = Obj()
>>> obj1.set_x()
>>> obj1.print_x()
1
>>> obj2 = Obj()
>>> obj2.set_x()
>>> obj2.print_x()
2
>>> obj1.print_x()
2
```

You should see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python) for some more information.

Comment: What C calls "static variables" are called "global variables" in Python (even though they're not truly global). That is what the code sample in the question uses. The type of variable you're using here is called a "class attribute."

Comment: @dirk, thanks about user queryset issue comment in my answer (in other question). +1